# Bootstrap 3.2.0. Overwrite print media css setting for table cells

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using plain bootstrap.css and overwriting styles with my stylesheet.  Bootstrap 3 has print media queries that make any tables with the .table class to print with plain white backgrounds.

My question is : What css do I use to overwrite Bootstrap's css setting for table cells?

My table is:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
    <tr class="table-stripe">
```

Note: I've created my own class called table-stripe as my table is too complex to use the built-in table-striped class (each block of information is actually two rows). However, the built-in .table-striped would have the same issue.

The line in Bootstrap which sets all the cells white when printed out is:

```
@media print {
  .table td,
  .table th {
    background-color: #fff !important;
  }
}
```

I don't know what to use in my overwrite css file to set the td overwrite to "none".

```
@media print {
    .table td,
    .table th {
        /* what goes here? */
    }

    .table-stripe {
            background-color: #dedede;
    }
}
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the suggestion I managed to get my css overwrite to show the table stripe in print preview with the following:

```
@media print {
    .table td,
    .table th {
            background-color: inherit !important;
    }

    .table-stripe {
            background-color: #dedede !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: what if table has huge amount of data and it requires page break? I have apply it but its not working

Answer (score 0):

remove `!important;` from bootstrap

add this to replace `background-color: inherit !important;`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I specifically don't want to touch the bootstrap css file but you did get me thinking about the !important. Managed to get it working, I'll edit my original post with the css I managed to get working.